# How to run an exe on a post build event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What is the correct script to run a certain `exe` file on a post build event?

Comment: An example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: Just as you would run this .exe from command-line. So, specify your .exe with full path and enclose it in double-quotes if either path or executable name contain spaces.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev: Thanks! Would you like to write it as answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just as you would run this .exe from command-line. So, specify your .exe with full path and enclose it in double-quotes if either path or executable name contain spaces.

Answer (score 12):

Provided answer is correct, however providing the full path is not always necessary.

Example: run one of the projects output executable.

- (optionally) Configure post-build event to run `Always`
- use a path relative to the project path. E.g.: `"$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\maybe_just_refreshed.exe"` or better version suggested by `m93a`: `"$(TargetDir)maybe_just_refreshed.exe"` (this compansates for the cases when output location is customized (not the default `bin\Debug`).

Comment: Instead of `"$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\maybe_just_refreshed.exe"` you could use `"$(TargetDir)maybe_just_refreshed.exe"`.

Comment: @m93a - I have incorporated your suggestion in the answer. Besides being shorter, it also works for custom output locations. Thanks.

Comment: @Latency - Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730003/msb3073-command-exited-with-code-9009). Do you correctly point to an executable file? ECHO commands might help to see in output the actual path that it is trying to execute.

Comment: call "$(TargetPath)"     <---  otherwise you get 9009 error.

Comment: @Latency - not sure, but I think`$(TargetPath)` points to the output executable / assembly folder while `$(ProjectDir)` points to project's base directory. So, the answer might need adapting based on actual setup (type of project, project build configuration etc.).

Comment: I already gave you the answer.  You have to 'call' the target variable to invoke it.

Comment: I cannot find how to configure post-build event to run `Always` with a VS2017 C++ project.

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers worked for me.

Even though my exe was at the file path I provided, it still exited with a code of "whatever" and never worked.

Then I did this:

> cd $(ProjectDir)

> "MyProgram.exe"

...both on separate lines in the post build event command line editor.

My app is located in the project directory. They didn't work on the same line, but separate lines worked fine.