# Error MSB3073: The command "heat dir .." exited with code 9009

Tags: wix, wix3.8

C:\Subrata System\Projects\DemoWebsite\DemoWebsite.Demo\setup.build(55,5):error MSB3073: The command "heat dir ..\Setup\publish\ -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd
 -cg MyWebWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out WebSiteContent.wxs" exited
 with code 9009.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSB3073 'command' exited with code 9009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730003/msb3073-command-exited-with-code-9009)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the wix toolset is not accessible directly.
please give the complete path for heat.exe
like:

```
Command='"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\heat.exe" dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MyWebWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode) -t "HeatTransform.xslt"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running the command from a cmd prompt, but installed Wix Toolset while it was up. The solution is to run it from a new cmd prompt, the environment variables were not updated in the already opened one.

Comment: I don't think the WiX installer updates the PATH, rather it adds an environment variable called WIX intended for use in build scripts. You have to update the path yourself. Unless this was changed recently.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. There is no PATH update done in the official WiX installer. This is definitely intentional (security issues, path can pick up undesirable side-by-side versions, path variable is vulnerable, there is more - I am no expert on this...). However, they set the environment variable WIX to the installation path of the toolkit. You can hence use that as follows in a **`cmd.exe`**: **`"%WIX%bin\dark.exe"`** to invoke the binary tool **`dark.exe`** located in the bin folder. Same with **`candle`** and **`light`**. I haven't used this, but should work OK.